# bootstrap 4 flex rows are appearing side by side

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm new to flex, and my boss wants me to use only flexbox for this! the problem is I am trying to get the nav menu to show in it's own row, but it keeps wrapping to be right next to the search icon, etc. I have it in it's own row in the code, so I don't know why it's appearing side by side

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row w-100">
      <div class="flex-column">
          company logo here
      </div>
      <div class="flex-column">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          company name here
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-column justify-content-end">
        search icon here
      </div>
      <div class="flex-column justify-content-end">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row w-100">
      <div class="flex-column justify-content-start">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>    
          </ul>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a CSS rule :

```
.navbar-expand-lg > .container {
  flex-wrap:wrap
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djrq7w85/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean that the button of the menu keeps appearing next to the search icon. That's because the button is in the same row as the search icon. You are right that the menu itself is in its own row, but the button is not.